# Compute $z^3 = |z|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Compute $z^3 = |z|$

$z = 0$ is a solution

when $z$ is not zero, I get to $z^2 = z'$ , how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $|z^3|=|z|^3$, we get $|z|^3=|z|$. Real solutions to this are $0$ and $1$.

If $|z|=0$, then $z=0$.

If $|z|=1$, the equation becomes $z^3=1$, with solutions $e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{3}}$, where $k=0,1,2$.

Comment: but how can you replace $z$ with $|z|^3$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I didn't. I took the absolute value of both sides of your equation.

Answer (score 3):

In polar coordinates, $z=re^{i\theta}$, so:
$$r^3e^{3i\theta}=r$$
If $r\neq0$, you simply have that $3\theta=2\pi n$, or that:$$\theta=0, 2\pi/3, 4\pi/3$$
And $r$ of course must be equal to one.